# retrieve multiples values from a function

Tags: javascript, function, return, coordinates

What I'm doing wrong? I trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude values from the function but I receive is undefined.

```
var getPos = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) 
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) 
    {
      var lat = p.coords.latitude,
      lng = p.coords.longitude;
      return [lat, lng];        
    })

  }
}

var co = getPos(), 
    la = co[0],
    ln = co[1];
alert(la+ln);
```

Comment: You're not returning anything. That `return` is inside another scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, that is why you are not receiving anything, you could use a callback and act on the returned values, like so:

```
var getPos = function(callback) {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {
      var rlat = p.coords.latitude,
      lng = p.coords.longitude;
      callback([lat, lng]);        
    })
  }
};
getPos(function(lat, long) {
  // do what you need with those
});
```

You could read about that in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation):

> To obtain the user's current location, you can call the getCurrentPosition() method. This initiates an asynchronous request to detect the user's position, and queries the positioning hardware to get up-to-date information.

Comment: Hi Alberto, thanks for your answer, I new in this... And I dont understand very well how can I acces to the values from anywhere when I need. like i need the coordinates in one point so I ask at my function and I could acces

Comment: You define a function as you did and invoke it where you need, I am not getting your point, I'm open to helping you though, please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks again, and sorry for my english... what I need is make a function that I could call from any place in my app and retrieve the coordinates for use in the moment that I need for example when I need to load a map so I just call the function and retrieve the coordinates this is posible? and thanks again for your pascience and atention.

Comment: Yes it is possible, what kind of application is that? Do you have a scope or global variable you could attach your function to?

Comment: thank you very much, it was just what I needed. But  for my inexperience I take more time for understand